# Styling two divs on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I am new to front end so please forgive me if this is a naive question.

I am trying to implement a simple shadow effect on div
if user hover's first one the second dive should also have shadow effect

Scenario: image1|text1 image2|text2 image3|text3
If user hovers image1, I should get boreder over image and text1 same for image2 and image 3 
link to codepen: http://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/xOZVzr

I have tried two things tried keeping image2|text2 in single dive but didnt work
And want it responsive

Css:

```
 .trio img {
    padding: 1px;
  max-width: 250px;
  width: 100%;
    height: auto;
  text-align:center;
  float:left;
}
```

Rephrasing question:

```
   <div class="trio">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 gold_trio">
            <a href="index.php?rt=product/category&path=68" ><img src="http://s3.hulkshare.com/avatar_images/original/a/4/5/a45d67ab944b162b11d39075321357bd.jpg?dd=1388552400"  title="GOLD"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 gold_trio">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip 
            </p>
            </a>
        </div>
 </div>
```

If I hover on trio border should come on class trio

Answer (score 1):

I have mentioned before comment there was also problem in HTMl structure. so I have fixed that as well. `a` tag was starting and closing at wrong position

but now its fixed

have fun.

**UPDATED**

**HTML**

```
    <div class="trio">
              <a href="index.php?rt=product/category&path=68">
                <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 gold_trio">
               <img src="http://s3.hulkshare.com/avatar_images/original/a/4/5/a45d67ab944b162b11d39075321357bd.jpg?dd=1388552400" title="GOLD" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 gold_trio">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip
              </p>
            </div>
          </a>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
  .trio img {
    padding: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    float: left;
  }

  .trio {
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .trio:hover {
    border: solid 1px red;
  }
```

Comment: Thanks prince, but I want a border which contains image and text together now it borders image a seperate box then p tag separate box
So if you hover image 1 border should box image1 and text1

Comment: aha ok I got it . your HTML was broken, I need to chk it again, could you please upload image for working example.

Comment: http://codepen.io/rahulv/pen/xOZVzr  paraghraph should come beside image so its 3 images and text in row

Comment: yaa I have you codepen code. but its doesnot look like right. it looks like https://img42.com/6E2Gv (this image will live for 10 minutes). 
http://imgur.com/a/tstmQ

Comment: You can use any image 250*250 pixel  and then there is text beside each image in one row
I guess If you click on image it goes because of anchor tag and the path is set for local

Answer (score 0):

use jquery or javascript for smarter way. i know you new with front end so just made simple changes

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="trio">
        <div id="gold_trio"  class="div_trio">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="index.php?rt=product/category&path=68" ><img src="http://s3.hulkshare.com/avatar_images/original/a/4/5/a45d67ab944b162b11d39075321357bd.jpg?dd=1388552400"  title="GOLD"></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="silver_trio" class="div_trio">
             <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                  <a href="index.php?rt=product/category&path=68" ><img src="http://s3.hulkshare.com/avatar_images/original/a/4/5/a45d67ab944b162b11d39075321357bd.jpg?dd=1388552400"  title="GOLD"></a>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip  </p>
              </div>
      </div>

        <div id="user_trio"  class="div_trio">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                <a href="index.php?rt=product/category&path=68" ><img src="http://s3.hulkshare.com/avatar_images/original/a/4/5/a45d67ab944b162b11d39075321357bd.jpg?dd=1388552400"  title="GOLD"></a>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip  </p>
            </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

just use this bit of code for css

```
 .trio img {
padding: 1px;
max-width: 250px;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
text-align:center;
float:left;
```

}

and rest done by jquery

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".div_trio").hover(function () {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "0 0 10px black");
        }, function () {
            $(this).css("box-shadow", "none");
        });
    });
</script>
```